Use PEM-file as truststore in Spring Boot
I have exported a self-signed certificate from a website with the following command:
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 111.111.111.11:8443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM > mycertfile.pem

Then I tried to use it as a truststore in my Spring Boot app. For this I put the file into resources folder:
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
...
│       └── resources
│           ├── application.yaml
│           └── mycertfile.pem

and added the corresponding option to application.yml
server:
  ssl:
    trust-store: "classpath:mycertfile.pem"
spring:
  application:
...

However the following exception occurs when the app starts:
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:84) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.sitronics.gateway.GatewayApplication.main(GatewayApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create trust store: Could not load store from 'classpath:mycertificate.pem'
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.createKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:94) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.<init>(JksSslStoreBundle.java:58) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
...

What isn't done properly here?
